# How to avoid Image size shrink when aligning

Tags: swift, swiftui

New to this framework i know i'm not good at aligning part of UI yet.

My aligning problem is my image get shrink the more padding it has so if possible can you go easy and point out my mistake here? i am practicing align my item to top left corner.

```
    struct MasterLabMerge: View {
    var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
        Image(systemName: "note")
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .padding(.leading, -300)
            .padding(.top, -500)
      }
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Using hardcoded values is generally considered bad practice with SwiftUI, try viewing this view on a small device such as an iPhone SE or an iPod touch. Use percentages with GeometryReader instead

Comment: thank and bless you lorem and asperi

Comment: my next course is geometryreader

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.resizable()` to enable an image to grow in size.

Also, you can align your item to the top left in better ways.

Option 1 (I personally think this is the best):

```
 ZStack {
   Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
   VStack {
     HStack {
         Image(systemName: "note")
             .resizable()
             .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
             .padding(.leading)
         Spacer()
     }
     Spacer()
   }
 }
```

Option 2:

```
 ZStack {
    Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Image(systemName: "note")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .padding(.top)
        }
    }
```